# Fullcalendar, active current month

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I am trying to create a calendar which shows all months and has a functionality to select a month and display it. Here is my code for the month selection:

```
<ul id="months-tab">
    <li><a href="#" data-month="0">January </a></li>
    .
    <li><a href="#" data-month="11">December </a></li>
</ul>
<div id='calendar'></div>
```

And here is the code for showing a month according to the selected month and the currently active month:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/locale/th.js"></script>

<script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            defaultDate: '2018-03-12',
            editable: true,
            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
            events: [
                {
                title: 'All Day Event',
                start: '2018-03-01'
                }
            ]
        });

        $('#months-tab a').click(function() {
            var month = $(this).attr('data-month');
            var m = moment([moment().year(), month, 1]);

            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', m );
        });

        $("#months-tab li").click(function(){
            if($(this).attr('data-month') == $(this).attr('data-month')){
                $(this).addClass("active");
            }
        })
    });
</script>
```

So how can I activate the current month after a month has been selected?

**My issue is**

1. it doesn't activate first month to active have to click any month they it will active
2. once active then active another one previous month still remain activate

Comment: didn't understand your requirement

Comment: I want to active month according to selected month in fullcalendar

Comment: and what problem are you facing when you try that? It's clear what you want, but not what your issue is currently.

Comment: My issue is 
1. it doesn't activate first month to active have to click any month they it will active
2. once active then active another one previous month still remain activate

Comment: for 1. you'd have to set the month explicitly after the page loads, without waiting for a click. You just need another line of code probably, to set the current month as the first active one. 2. You're not doing anything which would make the previous tab inactive. You need to add a "removeClass" command to remove the active class from all tabs before you add it to the newly active one.

Comment: @ADyson (First of all sorry for my bad english) I have update it 
actually i a new on Jquery so i am not much familiar to it. i have added "removeClass" but it's not working

Comment: please show exactly what you added and where you added it

Comment: One other thing.... `if($(this).attr('data-month') == $(this).attr('data-month')){`...this is completely redundant. You are comparing a value with itself...so clearly it will always return true. Not sure what you thought this line was for?

Comment: @ADyson I want to check that is current month(Fullcalendar) == data-month="" or not if yes then active that month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a demo of what you need, making it simpler by removing the hyperlink tags - you simply don't need them. It's easier just to have everything on the `<li>` rather than having two tags. The hyperlink doesn't really add anything useful as far as I can see.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    defaultDate: '2018-03-12',
    editable: true,
    eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
    events: [{
      title: 'All Day Event',
      start: '2018-03-01'
    }]
  });

  //set current month's tab to active
  var month = $("#calendar").fullCalendar("getDate").month();
  $("#months-tab li[data-month='" + month + "']").addClass("active");

  $('#months-tab li').click(function() {
    var link = $(this);
    var month = link.attr('data-month');
    var m = moment([moment().year(), month, 1]);

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', m);
    $("#months-tab li").removeClass("active");
    link.addClass("active");
  });


});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

li.active {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  border: solid 1px blue;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>


<ul id="months-tab">
  <li data-month="0">January</li>
  <li data-month="1">February</li>
  <li data-month="2">March</li>
  <li data-month="3">April</li>
  <li data-month="4">May</li>
  <li data-month="5">June</li>
  <li data-month="6">July</li>
  <li data-month="7">August</li>
  <li data-month="8">September</li>
  <li data-month="9">October</li>
  <li data-month="10">November</li>
  <li data-month="11">December</li>
</ul>
<div id='calendar'></div>
```

Comment: Wow it works! Thank you sir. Thanks a lot for all your help. ^^